# How to store Geopoint to Firebase with Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-maps, google-cloud-firestore

I have set up a Textformfield where users can fill in their shop & Geopoint coordinates.

They then press the submit button and it updates on our Firestore collection.

The problem I am having is how to save it as Geopoint's and not a string.

```
SizedBox(child: ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () async { 
    await collectionReference.add({ 
      'shopName':  _textEditingController.text,
      'address': _textEditingController2.text, 
      'description': _textEditingController3.text, 
      'thumbNail': _textEditingController4.text,
      'locationCoords':_textEditingController5.GeoPoint
    },);
  },
  chil:Text('Add Data'),
))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geopoint there is GeoPoint object inside Firestore plugin

```
'locationCoords':GeoPoint(_textEditingController5.GeoPoint.latitude,_textEditingController5.GeoPoint.longitude);
```

Comment: This worked

Would I need to change my Text Controller as well?
final _textEditingController5 = TextEditingController();

How do I allow it to accept coordinates?

Comment: according to your needs, the main thing is to recover longitude and attitude